# Trying to set up Apache redirect thing

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, redirect

I'm trying to set up my apache server to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com and I am having troubles. To save me re-posting where I'm at and what I've tried here is a link to my existing post on LQ.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5348110

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to add redirect line to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.vhost` file for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can read more about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100343/apache-redirect-from-non-www-to-www